# How to wait after UI thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

In my Activity, I have a method that makes the font size bigger or smaller, depending on the width of a TextView. I do a setText on the TextView to enter a new value (which will most likely increase or decrease the width of the ViewText) and then go right into my method. My problem is that when I enter my method, the size of the TextView has not changed yet, so I'm guessing the UI thread is taking a bit more time to accomplish the resize of the TextView and my method does not work because of that. So how do I wait after the UI thread so that I can correctly execute the code of my method?

This is the code of my main activity. The method texteAffichage is just setting what is in my TextView and gestionPolice is resizing the font if it needs to. When I do a sysout in gestionPolice, I never get the current width of the TextView, because it seems like it did not have time to do that.

```
affichage.setText(texteAffichage((Button) v));
gestionPolice();
```

Comment: if you're calling `setText` and your method in the same thread, your method shouldn't get called before the `setText` is finished... I think there may be something else going on

Comment: Mind posting your code?

Comment: It seems like a very small delay of 10 seconds fixes my problem!

Comment: But it is very ugly because of the delay.

Comment: Sorry, don't have time to write full answer. Delays are not the answer and will be ugly and extremely fragile (speed, GPU? a million other things). You cannot be sure that any delay is OK (what happens if the users phone rings?). Check `GlobalLayoutListener`.  It will callback when something in the layout changes requiring a remeasure. You could test in the callback and do the work there.  Alternatively, extend TextView and add an `Interface` to call your activity back when the font changes by overriding font change method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could **delay** your code using a **Handler**:

```
 Handler h = new Handler();

 h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
         // DO DELAYED STUFF
     }
 }, your_variable_amount_of_time); // e.g. 3000 milliseconds
```

**Side note:** I do not think that your problem occurs because the setText(...) method takes too much time. Post your code so that others can have a look at it.

Comment: Delaying a fixed amount of time is generally a bad idea.

Comment: 10 seconds, but it is very ugly now because of the delay haha

Comment: Even if I put 1 ms of delay it's not good enough, I need to find a better solution, but thank you for the help.

Comment: Ahh I found a good solution. I can hide the TextView, call my method in a new runnable a you suggested and show back the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be something like:

```
        tv.setText("someText");
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int width = tv.getWidth();
                // your code reacting to the change in width
            }
        }, 50);
```

50 miliseconds should be enough for the change in UI to complete but fast enough for the user not to notice.

As Simon correctly points out this is not necessarily the best solution. To give you an example of how you might use **GlobalLayoutListener**:

```
    final ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            width = tv.getWidth();
            // your code reacting to the change in width

        }
    });
```

Comment: You are welcome. Just discovered that there is a addTextChangedListener method on TextViews, which might have been cleaner, but was unable to confirm it as a working solution. As so far setText has not called any of the listeners methods when I issue setText. However, the 50ms delay does the trick anyway.