# Android TextView.setText() + getDrawingCache(), text is not visible in Bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-view

I've problem with `getDrawingCache()` and `setText()` of `TextView`. I do not see text in Bitmap after `setText()` and used `getDrawingCache()`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparencyGray"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/idOfTextView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="@color/white"
         android:shadowColor="@color/black"
         android:shadowDx="0"
         android:shadowDy="0"
         android:shadowRadius="5"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeLarge"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code is:

```
idOfTextView.setText( "Some special test string" );
// create bitmap screen capture
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
//v1.invalidate();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Bitmap has correct resolution, correct mainLinearLayout background (set programmatically, not in this example), but i do not see text:"Some special test string" from `idOfTextView.setText( "Some special test string" )` in Bitmap.

Interesting is: when i add `android:text="Test string"` to idOfTextView, part of text ("Some") is showed in Bitmap.

When i comment `setText()` in code and add `android:text="Test string"` to idOfTextView, everything is OK.

I tried: edit layout, invalidate, setVisibility, searching on Google, but i do not know, what's next now.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inspired by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18752120/4244605).
Solution:

```
idOfTextView.setText( "Some special test string" );
final View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
final ViewTreeObserver vto = affirmation.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    }
});
```